# Mail merging and automatic receipt of responses

Tags: web-apps, email, automation, merge

I am tasked with collecting and updating a table with some performance metrics (e.g. no of metrics, no. of citations etc), for about twenty people. One specification is that I don't want the different people to have access to other people's data.

So ideally I would like for each individual to:

- send a form filled with their previously collected data and mail it to them (mailing a document is not necessary it may be an online form).
- automatically collect the data and create a new table with the new/updated data.

Ideally, I would prefer it to be everything online without clogging up my email account, so feel free to suggest anything that may be useful.